# Elementary Row Operations as Functions

Tags: linear-algebra

I’m currently working through Hoffman’s Linear Algebra, in the following at the bottom I do not understand  what he is trying to communicate with the expression

$$ e(A)_{ij} = A_ij $$

[image]

for the the three different row operations. The way it is laid out is a conditional statement, but I just can’t wrap my head around why he includes it at all.

Answer (score 0):

$e(A)=B$ is a function that takes a matrix $A$ and returns a new matrix, which for convenience I'm going to call $B$. Using $B$ in these expressions, we would write $B_{ij}=A_{ij}$ if $i\neq r$, which just means that for the rows other than $r$, the elements of the new matrix are the same as those from the old matrix.